# HTTP basic auth is not working

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am creating an api with Laravel 4.1. For authentication I wanted to use Laravel Basic auth. Every time I fill the input fields, it doesn't let me in. It just clear the input and popup the form again. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am not using migration for creating users table. This is just a basic route:

```
Route::get('admin', function()
{
    return "authenticated";

})->before('auth.basic');
```

This is my filter:

```
Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic('username');
});
```

This is my User Model:

```
 <?php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'pivot');

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = array('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'is_admin');

    protected $fillable = array('username', 'password', 'name_first', 'name_middle', 'name_last', 'email', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code', 'country', 'phone', 'title', 'profile_image', 'status');
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = array();


    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try

```
Route::get('admin', array( 'before' => 'auth.basic' ,function()
{
    return "authenticated";
}));
```

Your passwords need to be hashed in your database.

Comment: can you check your code? your code has syntax error on 'do' => function()

Comment: @user2293111 Sorry I didn't. See if it works now. Are you sure you enter the right *username,password*?

Comment: yes the username and password is correct. Is there any way I can debug ?

Comment: I mean are there inside you database? Are the passwords `hashed`?

Comment: yes the problem is solved. The password need to be hashed. Thanks

Comment: @user2293111 Can I ask you something, where did you saw `})->before('auth.basic');`?